# Need to extract he rows which have the same column names in common between 2 tables and show only the 2nd table common rows

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables.

1st table contain the columns which are:

```
component ID, item name, item value
```

2nd table contains the columns which are:

```
component ID, biscuits,chocolates
```

If both the component ID in both tables matches (Ex :component 1 in table1= component 1 in table 2), return all the rows matched with component in table 2.

I am new to SQL and I am finding it difficult to do so.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `inner join`

```
select t2.* from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1 on t2.componentId=t1.componentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner join Table 1 with Table 2 using component id column and return all the rows from Table 1. As a reference use the below query.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 AS t1
   INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ComponentId = t2.ComponentId
```

Comment: I am getting error for AS t1 saying "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: which database you are using? Please change the syntax using your database engine language. This syntax will work in SQL Server

Comment: oracle sql I am using

Comment: For oracle you may need to put a ; at the end of the query,

Comment: is there anyway to do it as it will work if I put  SELECT t1.*, t2.* but i think that will give wrong result